# Will repeatedly normalizing an IEEE floating point vector mutate it?

Tags: floating-point

If I take a (nonzero) floating point vector (an `(x, y, z)` vector), and normalize it to unit length, is normalizing it a second time guaranteed to return the same result?

Comment: It would be best to show the code you are using to normalize the vector. What do you observe when you compare normalized and re-normalized vector for a bunch of random raw vectors? A quick ad-hoc test seems to indicate that differences between the normalized and the re-normalized vector are common.

Comment: The title and the question ask opposing questions (will the vector mutate, will the vector stay the same). I suggest one of them be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of a relevant result from the literature. A quick test demonstrates that normalizing a 3D-vector twice frequently leads to small differences between the normalized vector and the re-normalized one, even when care is taken to perform the normalization accurately, for example, by performing it in higher-precision arithmetic. I used the ISO-C99 program below for this quick test, compiling it with my compiler's "strict" floating-point settings (`icl /fp:strict`) for an x64 platform.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define USE_HYPOT  (1)

// Fixes via: Greg Rose, KISS: A Bit Too Simple. http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/007
static uint32_t z=362436069,w=521288629,jsr=362436069,jcong=123456789;
#define znew (z=36969*(z&0xffff)+(z>>16))
#define wnew (w=18000*(w&0xffff)+(w>>16))
#define MWC  ((znew<<16)+wnew)
#define SHR3 (jsr^=(jsr<<13),jsr^=(jsr>>17),jsr^=(jsr<<5)) /* 2^32-1 */
#define CONG (jcong=69069*jcong+13579)                     /* 2^32 */
#define KISS ((MWC^CONG)+SHR3)

float uint32_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
    float r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof(r));
    return r;
}

void normalize_3d (float *a, float *b, float *c)
{
#if USE_HYPOT
    double l = hypot (hypot ((double)a[0], (double)b[0]), (double)c[0]);
#else // USE_HYPOT
    double l = sqrt ((double)a[0]*a[0] + (double)b[0]*b[0] + (double)c[0]*c[0]);
#endif // USE_HYPOT
    *a = (float)((double)a[0] / l);
    *b = (float)((double)b[0] / l);
    *c = (float)((double)c[0] / l);
}

int main (void)
{
    float a, aa, aaa, b, bb, bbb, c, cc, ccc;
    do {
        /* generate random vector */
        do {
            a = uint32_as_float (KISS & ~0x80000000u);
        } while (isnanf (a) || (a > 0x1.0p126f) || (a < 0x1.0p-126f));
        do {
            b = uint32_as_float (KISS & ~0x80000000u);
        } while (isnanf (b) || (b > 0x1.0p126f) || (b < 0x1.0p-126f));
        do {
            c = uint32_as_float (KISS & ~0x80000000u);
        } while (isnanf (c) || (c > 0x1.0p126f) || (c < 0x1.0p-126f));

        /* normalize vector once */
        aa = a; bb = b; cc = c;
        normalize_3d (&aa, &bb, &cc);

        /* re-normalize normalized vector */
        aaa = aa; bbb = bb; ccc = cc;
        normalize_3d (&aaa, &bbb, &ccc);

        /* check whether normalized vector is equal to re-normalized one */
        if ((aa != aaa) || (bb != bbb) || (cc != ccc)) {
            printf ("norm = (%15.6a, %15.6a, %15.6a)  re-norm = (%15.6a, %15.6a, %15.6a)\n", aa, bb, cc, aaa, bbb, ccc);
        }
    } while (1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What if using `hypot(hypot(a,b),c)` to compute the norm?

Comment: @aka.nice Thanks for raising the point, I should have covered that as an alternate code path. Added now. With `hypot()` differences between normalized and re-normalized vectors are still common.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not guaranteed. Assuming all single-precision floats for the computation of the normalization, the following provides a counterexample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void normalize(float a, float b, float c, float *outA, float *outB, float *outC)
{
    float norm = sqrtf (a*a+b*b+c*c);
    *outA = a / norm;
    *outB = b / norm;
    *outC = c / norm;
}

int main(void)
{
    float a =  -4.33681e-19;
    float b = -1.326157e-23;
    float c = 2.8502696e-20;

    float a1, b1, c1;
    normalize(a, b, c, &a1, &b1, &c1);

    float a2, b2, c2;
    normalize(a1, b1, c1, &a2, &b2, &c2);

    printf("Original        : (%a, %a, %a)\n", a,  b,  c);
    printf("Normalized      : (%a, %a, %a)\n", a1, b1, c1);
    printf("Twice normalized: (%a, %a, %a)\n", a2, b2, c2);
}
```

This prints:

```
Original        : (-0x1.000006p-61, -0x1.00841ep-76, 0x1.0d334ap-65)
Normalized      : (-0x1.fee5d8p-1, -0x1.ffed76p-16, 0x1.0c9eeap-4)
Twice normalized: (-0x1.fee5d4p-1, -0x1.ffed72p-16, 0x1.0c9ee8p-4)
```

Even if you did the normalization using double-precision, you can still find counter-examples where the result changes.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this and it seems you can get various sorts of behaviour. For the examples below I used

```
hypotf( a, hypotf( b,c ))
```

to compute the length.
The tables below show the three cordinates, and then the length.
Sometimes you get eventual oscillation between two values:

```
    -0.000891105     0.402476907     0.915429652     0.999999881
    -0.000891105     0.402476966     0.915429771     0.999999881
    -0.000891105     0.402476907     0.915429652     1.000000119
    -0.000891105     0.402476966     0.915429771     0.999999881
    -0.000891105     0.402476907     0.915429652     1.000000119
    -0.000891105     0.402476966     0.915429771     0.999999881
    -0.000891105     0.402476907     0.915429652     1.000000119
    -0.000891105     0.402476966     0.915429771     0.999999881
    -0.000891105     0.402476907     0.915429652     1.000000119
    -0.000891105     0.402476966     0.915429771     0.999999881
    -0.000891105     0.402476907     0.915429652     1.000000119
```

Sometimes you get more complex behaviour:

```
 0.659812868     0.745291650     0.095850535     0.999999940
 0.659812927     0.745291710     0.095850542     0.999999940
 0.659812868     0.745291650     0.095850527     1.000000119
 0.659812927     0.745291710     0.095850535     0.999999940
 0.659812868     0.745291650     0.095850520     1.000000119
 0.659812927     0.745291710     0.095850527     0.999999940
 0.659812868     0.745291650     0.095850512     1.000000119
 0.659812927     0.745291710     0.095850520     0.999999940
 0.659812868     0.745291650     0.095850505     1.000000119
 0.659812927     0.745291710     0.095850512     0.999999940
 0.659812868     0.745291650     0.095850497     1.000000119
 0.659812927     0.745291710     0.095850505     0.999999940
 0.659812868     0.745291650     0.095850490     1.000000119
 0.659812927     0.745291710     0.095850497     0.999999940
 0.659812868     0.745291650     0.095850483     1.000000119
 0.659812927     0.745291710     0.095850490     0.999999940
 0.659812868     0.745291650     0.095850475     1.000000119
 0.659812927     0.745291710     0.095850483     0.999999940
 0.659812927     0.745291710     0.095850483     1.000000000
 0.659812927     0.745291710     0.095850483     1.000000000
 0.659812927     0.745291710     0.095850483     1.000000000
```