# Floating point inaccuracies breaks idempotence in weird ways

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I was wondering how bad floating point inaccuracies can get when normalizing vectors, specifically a 3D one. Normalizing once should give the same value as normalizing twice, but, as expected, floating point inaccuracies don't guarantee us that. So I decided to test some other things: if you normalize indefinitely, will it always "converge" to a value that normalizes to itself? The answer is no. For example, a few seconds testing and I found a value that loops between 2: `-0.60445204839058564 -0.54547899327834748 -0.58059485795902943` and `-0.60445204839058575 -0.54547899327834759 -0.58059485795902954`. Some "converge" after 3, 5 steps. Here's my boring code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

struct Point
{
    double x, y, z;
    bool operator==(const Point& o) const
    {
        return
            x == o.x &&
            y == o.y &&
            z == o.z;
    }
};

auto square(auto x)
{
    return x * x;
}

Point normalize(const Point& p)
{
    auto l = sqrt(square(p.x) + square(p.y) + square(p.z));
    return { p.x / l, p.y / l, p.z / l };
}

std::mt19937 mt(24);
std::uniform_real_distribution d(-1., 1.);

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        auto
            x = d(mt),
            y = d(mt),
            z = d(mt);

        Point p{ x, y, z };

        auto
            n1 = normalize(p),
            n2 = normalize(normalize(p));
        int cnt = 1;
        while (n1 != n2)
        {
            n1 = n2;
            cnt++;
            n2 = normalize(n2);
            auto len = square(n2.x) + square(n2.y) + square(n2.z);
            if (len != 1.)
            {
                __debugbreak();
            }
        }
        if (cnt != 2)
        {
            cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z
                << " took " << cnt << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

So I have a few curiosities:

1. What inputs create the longest loop/cycle and never converge?
2. What inputs take longest to converge?
3. After normalizing once, what input gives the maximum error from a length of 1?

Comment: Three questions in one Question. Be cautious. This may be make the Question too broad. If you can tie the three together better or drop one the Question may squeak through. Sometimes one question may answer or imply an answer to one of the other questions.

Comment: I think this largely depends on what bits overflow when the vector components are being squared and added. That's where the precision loss occurs. And the square root won't be 100% precise either. If you're at the point where those last few bits of precision are mission-critical, then you really need a wider/custom datatype or a more advanced normalization algorithm.

Comment: I put many questions to exemplify how one can wonder many things, but if any of the questions are answered, I'm happy

Comment: You’re going to need to bound the problem some more. For large coordinates, `square(p.x) + square(p.y) + square(p.z)` will generate infinity even though the true magnitude with the square root applied is in the finite range of the floating-point format, and then the normalization will return {0, 0, 0}. That might be the answer to question 3, about the maximum error from a length of 1.

Comment: Yes, we can tag that

Comment: @EricPostpischil we can bound the initial vector to [-1, 1], or whatever one wants

Comment: My mistake, there are tiny coordinates for which `square(p.x) + square(p.y) + square(p.z)` generates zero even though the true magnitude is non-zero, and then the normalization returns some vector of infinite magnitude, so the answer to question 3 is a tiny vector (such as {2^−1000, 2^−1000, 2^-1000}), which produces an error of infinity. These cases can be excluded by requiring the coordinates to be in a range where their squares produce neither 0 nor ±∞, but then that excludes some possibly interesting cases, such as one where one of the squares is zero but the others are not.

Comment: @Powereleven note that the underflow issue Eric is referring to is the reason that the [`hypot` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot) exists, you might get some ideas to improve stability from its implementation

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663382/will-repeatedly-normalizing-an-ieee-floating-point-vector-mutate-it

Comment: Some crude analysis: In the worst case, the two sums in `x*x+y*y+z*z` are in the same binade as the ideal sum of squares and have an error of u/2 each, where u is the ULP in that binade. The worst cases in the individual squares is one is in the same binade, one is one lower, and the third is two lower, with error bounds of u/2, u/4, and u/8. (Different distributions are possible with a lower sum.) So the total error is at most u/2 + u/2 + u/2 + u/4 + u/8 = 1⅞u. The square root very nearly halves the error and possibly adds ½ an ULP of its ideal result, so we would be at 23/16 ULP…

Comment: … That is below 1½ ULP, so not enough to round up to 2 ULP from the ideal result. So I think the calculation can produce a result at most 1 ULP above the ideal. This all assumes we stay in the normal finite range. We also need an analysis for for how far under we can be. Then the bounds on the square root might let us say something about the subsequent calculation of the normalized vector.

Comment: Please show an example that converges after 5 or more steps.

Comment: I changed the code so that the number of steps it takes to converge is the steps until it reaches the first value that normalizes to itself (it was one more before). Here are a few, the last number is the number of steps: `-0.70780427110711175 0.55374139992655635 -0.28498566462180042 4,
0.64679530611411673 0.44712230294444510 -0.81763445322334127 5,
0.66990802649058079 0.66007572245979906 -0.044634612876249147 72`

Comment: Interesting, since I thought the floating-point behaviors would drive convergence faster. The 5 case reproduces (as 4) with `float`, which makes it easy to study the rounding in each operation (do it in `double` and show the extra bits before rounding to `float`). In the 72 case, each of the first two coordinates alternates between its final value and 1 ULP less while the third coordinate steps its way from −34 and −35 ULP toward 0, not monotically, and finally circles the final point a little before hitting it. I might be interested in looking at it more but do not know when I will have time.

Comment: Adjusting the z coordinate in the 72 case by 48 ULP upward in magnitude yields a 172 case.